# How to to add external nusoap library in a custom extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom

I have to include external NUSOAP library in my custom made extension. What steps do I have to take as PHP's `require_once()` or `include()` doesn't work in Magento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please include your nusoap.php inside lib folder, (for example ) :

`magento_root_folder/lib/nusoap/nusoap.php`

so it can be called with this code part :

```
require_once Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'lib'.DS.'nusoap'.DS.'nusoap.php';

$client = new nusoap_client(...);
```

hope this help